# MySql PHP consulta de id varchar lo hace como numerico

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

Tengo una base de datos MySql, un id de alumno es un varchar de 11, en este campo se guardan números pero puede comenzar en ceros. por ejemplo 00000321. pero también puede almacenar 000321, pero al consultar por medio de jquery a PHP con id 0321 sin los ceros iniciales, muestra cualquiera de los anteriores o el primero que encuentra.

el codigo donde se envian los datos a php es el siguiente:

```
$.post("llenadoAl.php", {"id":$(".id_alm").val()}, function(data)
```

para manejar esta clase de códigos se creó varchar y no puede ser numérico por que eliminaría los ceros al inicio del id.

¿cómo puedo hacer la consulta que encuentre el código exactamente igual con los ceros a la izquierda?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la consulta `SQL` que usas para seleccionar el alumno con id = `x`?

Comment: Cuando pasas el id a php, en php lo sigues recibiendo con los ceros delante? (Entiendo que sí, pero por confirmar) Saludos!

Comment: Deberías mostrarnos tu consulta y el código correspondiendo del `llenadoAl.php` ... aquí una demostración [consulta SQL con Id varchar](https://goo.gl/ed33cL)

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que tu `$_Post` se envia bien (con los 0s que comentas etc...). Lo primero que deberias hacer es guardar tu `$_Post`

```
$texto = $_POST["id"];
```

Imprimela para saber si va bien la cosa. Comprueba paso a paso si se esta pasando correctamente, asi veras donde te falla.

Por último, lo unico que tendras que hacer es usar tu variable en la query:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM nombre_tabla WHERE ID = '".$texto."'";
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta.  el $_post pasa bien ya que al guardar lo guarda con los ceros que son. ya en consulta es donde devuelve cualquier registro. será por que uso este $query: $query = sprintf("SELECT * FROM alumno WHERE id_alumno = ".$_POST["id"].";");

Comment: mete las comillas detras del id_alumno, porque sino lo estas metiendo como numerico. id_alumno=' ' . Ya que solo has metido las de abrir y cerrar el string.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si era ese el error.

Comment: selecciona esta como tu respuesta es muy acertada a tu problema y es correcto siempre que guardes texto o flotantes(decimales) usa las comillas simple en el dato tanto como en update como en la clausula where etc...